# Problem with Select Query using NestJs and Supabase

Tags: typescript, nestjs, supabase

I'm trying to simply retrieve entries from the 'colegios' table on a supabase using nestjs, but the const 'data' is empty, logging [] on the console.

This is my code:

## App.service.ts:

```
  async mostrarColegio() {
    const { data, error } = await this.supabase
    .from('colegios').select();
    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }
```

## App.controller.ts:

```
  @Get()
  @Render('Listar.ejs')
  async findAll(): Promise<colegio[]> {
    console.log(await this.appService.mostrarColegio());
    const data = await this.appService.mostrarColegio();
    return data;
}
```

## Listar.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colégios</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{ data }}
</body>
```

At first I tought that I was doing something wrong in the supabase createClient, but the insertion method works fine:

```
  async createColegio(nome_do_colegio: Colegio) {
      const { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('colegios').insert({ nome_do_colegio });
      if (error) {
          throw console.log(error);
      }
  }
```

## Expected Result

1- Entries from the table 'Colegios', like "teste1" and others.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try running the mostrarColegio() query in a separate script to see if you can retrieve data from the table just to narrow down if its a NestJS problem or something else

Comment: I tried running this script:
`import os
from supabase import create_client, Client

supabase: Client = create_client("MyURL", "MyAnonPublicKey")

print(supabase.table('colegios').select("*").execute())
`

and got this result from the terminal:

data=[] count=None

So I think I messed up something on the database

Comment: After running this script I decided to look into my table on supabase and realized I forgot to make a policie on select(), now it's working fine, logging on the terminal the data. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found two corrections that answer my problem:

**1**
I forgot to make a policie about select() om my database, after making it, the query runs fine.

**2**
Changing

```
      @Get()
      @Render('Listar.ejs')
      async findAll(): Promise<colegio[]> {
        console.log(await this.appService.mostrarColegio());
        const data = await this.appService.mostrarColegio();
        return data;
    }
```

To

```
      @Get()
      async findAll(): Promise<{ data: Colegio[] }> {
        console.log(await this.appService.mostrarColegio());
        const data = await this.appService.mostrarColegio();
        return { data };
      }
      @Render('Listar.ejs')
```

Made the data appear right on the 'Listar.ejs'.